# how to set equal font size in table cells for mobile device html pages

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I got a problem with font rendering on mobile devices.
I have a simple table width set fixed to 800 pixels, common size for todays mobiles.

Text in my cells all use the same html css makeup.
The text in the first row show ok

But the next row is a problem it is split into two cells.
The left cell is a picture and in the right cell there is some text.
My problem is that most mobile web browsers scale down the font size in that cell.

To me it would be oké if that text would simply be spread over a bit more lines but that doesn't happen, they tend to keep as much lines similar as in a desktop browser view.

I've set the font size using pt px and no effect in the css file like

```
.DefaultFont 
{
font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', Arial,verdena,sans-serif;
font-size: 13pt;
font-style: normal;
color:#4e0203;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

used 13pt 13em and other methods etc nothing worked.

And for the html element used span and div and p and tried it inside td element, but again no effect.

PS I'm not looking for javascript tricks for scaling pages client side with device detection etc. As i simply use php to determine if its a desktop or a mobile device (which requires less code to be transmitted). I just need the code so that the font wont change as caused by a mobile web browser.

How do i stop those clients from rescaling parts of tables ?

---

**SOLUTION**
The final solution that worked really nice was a combination of multiple people here.

- Set table width's in %
- Set font size in vw (which like % has also a 100 index), a low value like 2 or so.
- Note  vw is supported by lots more then just font size, also images.
- include the meta tag  it even worked without that after above, but to be on the safe side i recommend it.

Comment: can you replicate the case with http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: have you tried setting a the html font-size then make other element font-size: 1em;?

Comment: Try using % based values for your table cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should use viewport sized typography units for the `font-size`.

It can be used when you want to size thing through the viewport's (element container) width or height. Or both, for that matter. The possible values are:

**vh - viewport's height**
It sizes proportionaly to the container's height.

```
font-size: 2vh;
```

**vw - viewport's width** 
It sizes proportionaly to the container's width.

```
font-size: 2vw;
```

**vmin - viewport's minimum** 
It sizes proportionaly to the smaller between 'vh' and 'vw'.

```
 font-size: 2vmin;
```

**vmax - viewport's maximum** 
It sizes proportionaly to the larger between 'vh' and 'vw'.

```
 font-size: 2vmax;
```

It surely can give you the looks that you want. Just find the current proportional value, and no matter the screen's size, it will fit!

[**W3 viewport relative length's docs**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply i'm not working 100% yet (ill). Well i got to say this is a nice way of scaling fonts, and it even supports table width. quite nice. However i still got the problem in a cell of the table it looks smaller. When looking at the site trough a mobile.
I'd love to see it working using this vmin method.

Comment: Well i had to combine your tip on using vw in CSS. Together with using table width's as set by %. Percentage and vw values both have a hundred scale so that works nice together. Then i also had to set <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> as explained by @Srinivas. 
The result together is awesome, its scales automatic without scripting just CSS and a meta tag. I'd like to reward you since it was a verry good tip, although in the end i needed to combine all tips together to make it work as intended. Your tip made it work beyond of what i had intended super !

Comment: kinda amazing i got noted this question has now 2500 views (24-10-2017)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried Meta tags,to check if it works...

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the page at the width of its own screen. So if that screen is 320px wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default, in lieu of a responsive meta tag).

Check out,It may be helpful..

Comment: I'm getting close now, at first the main table was fixed and with above option it didnt fit inside the mobile, i'm now into tuning this with @LcSalazar; troughout the site. I'got to remove all fixed sizes in other formats but so far its going the right way i think.

Comment: since the answer was a combination of both you and LcSalazar, i voted him since you already had the 25 points, i really needed both for the design. Thanks for your tip.. oh and btw setting initial scale to something les like 0.7 or 1.5 gave back the old problem, initial-scale 1 in itself made my tables to large on mobile devices, so i set the table now 90% (for a bit background too) and the font size by CSS vw, and images also to vw, together this tapes scale to any device nicely.
Most things go fine with vw or %, some not like iframe height

Answer (score 0):

i think this should do the trick

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: I wasnt sure how this would work between different webkits, so i didnt test it perhaps it will go fine and it works, i based the solution around the other people's advice here, but i like to say thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.innerHeight`.